# How to show simulation time using Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, profiling

I've been asked to add a clock that displays the simulation time in my application. How can it be done?

Comment: simulation time for what?

Comment: There are plugins that can help you with that in eclipse, so you don't have to create your plugin for that unless that is your project, is it?

Comment: yeah this is my project, what plugin is it? how do i find it? been googling for last 3hrs still can't find the answer.

Comment: What the * are you asking??? Are you doing a simulation? Does it matter for displaying a time? Are you using Eclipse? Is you application using Eclipse? Does it matter? Sorry, but no wonder that you couldn't google out anything, they haven't implemented a crystal ball yet.

Answer (score 2):

If I understande you correctly, you are aiming at profiling your application performance. If that is what you are trying to do, then why don't you use a plugin for that instead of building your own?

Here is a plugin that can help you with your task
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html

Well it is more like a suite addresses the entire test and performance life cycle

Also try this one as well:
https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/

and you can always search in the eclipse market place for plugins of this kind here:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/

However you can also make your code measure its own speed/time. If this is just a personal project you are using to learn, it might not be such a bad idea as well.

Comment: umm not quite like that though, so basically I have to display the time when the application started, have control buttons that can pause/resume or make the application goes faster/slower

Comment: There should be such plugins in eclipse market place. However not sure you will find a plugin that make your software go faster or slower! Usually these plugs and tools are just to show you the performance (speed, memery usage, etc) in a visual way.

Comment: ummm, that's strange, but anyway thanks for the help:)

Comment: @user3600620 Can you explain what you mean by application go faster/slower? Maybe add information about what the application is doing. Are you trying to pause execution of the code?